# What are the typical stages / processes of a criminal trial?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, trial

In a criminal trial in the United States, there are stages or processes which are followed by every case heard by the courts. I understand some states may vary in procedure but what are the stages that are considered "standard" in every criminal court proceeding?  What are these stages or processes?

Comment: What resources have you consulted so far?  Also, given the tag are you interested in the federal system specifically, or including states?  There are notable variations between the states.

Comment: I researched several "criminal defense" attorney websites but they vary widely on the standard stages of a trial. I'm really interested if there are standard stages each court will take regardless of the state. If there significant differences between the steps in federal court vs state court then its ok to just pick the most common state court proceedings.